# Call Javascript onchange function when change dropdown value from another function

Tags: javascript

I have one drop down box

```
<select id="drp" onchange="setValue(this.value)">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>


function setValue(val)
{
    var temp=val;
}

function another_function()
{
    document.getElementById("drp").value="two"
}
```

When I set `drp` to "two" from the function `another_function`, I want to call `setValue()`. I wrote `another_function` from an explanation in my code about how to set dropdown value from JavaScript library. Is it possible to catch `onchange` event in the `setValue` function.

when set two value in dropdown box from another function i want to call setValue function. I wrote another_function from expanation actually in my code set dropdown value from JavaScript library. so is it possible to catch on change event in setValue function ?

Answer (score 1):

As you have found out, the `change` event isn't always triggered by all changes in certain elements. In particular, it's usually just mouse and keyboard interaction which trigger the event. You will have to "trigger" it manually wherever you change the value:

```
function another_function()
{
    var drp = document.getElementById("drp");
    drp.value="two";
    drp.onchange(); // Make sure the change event is triggered
}
```

Comment: I got you point but In project I have used Javascript library, this library can set the value in HTML control. It's a generic code.

Comment: @Hkachhia what library are you using?

Comment: We have created own javascript library for our project

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to be able to set the value without triggering `setValue`.

I would do this:

```
function setValue(val)
{
    var temp=val;
}

function another_function()
{
    var drp = document.getElementById("drp");
    var oldOnChange = drp.onchange;
    drp.onchange = function() {};
    drp.value = "two";
    drp.onchange = oldOnChange;
}
```

This will remove the event handler, set the value and then reinstate the event handler.

Comment: As I told my dropdown value is set from JavaScript library and in library wrote generic code so i am not able to edit it.

Comment: @Hkachhia I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding what you mean.

Comment: Okay i have clear here.  I want to call onchange function when dropdown value will change from another function. Or i want capture event when change value of dropdown from another function

Comment: Do you mean like `drp.onchange()`, that will trigger the `setValue` function?

Comment: It's call automatically when dropdown value change

Comment: @Hkachhia isn't that what Linus has answered above?

Comment: Is there anyway how to call on javascript function on value change of dropdown box ?

Comment: @Hkachhia If you mean "call **a** javascript function..." then yes, inside `setValue()` you would call some other function.

Comment: But how to call setValue function when update dropdown value from javascript library ?

Comment: call `drp.onchange()` as everyone has said. This will trigger whatever function you defined as the `onchange` event.

Answer (score -1):

simply you can change another_function like below

```
function another_function()
{
    document.getElementById("drp").value="two"
    setValue(document.getElementById("drp").value);
}
```